# onbeforeunload event parameter and empty return value

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onbeforeunload, confirm

Q1: I have seen the following code in most sources:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return 'You might lose your data!';
};
```

For example:

1. [beforeunload | onbeforeunload event (Internet Explorer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [onbeforeunload event | beforeunload event JavaScript](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhtbtum.php)
3. [javascript - How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276739/478018)

But on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload#Example) the function has an extra parameter: `(e)`. Why is that, what is the difference, and which is right?

Q2: It seems that any browser has a default confirmation message that you cannot customize. Chrome, for example, displays:

> Are you sure you want to leave this page?

Can I content myself to this message and leave the `return` value empty:

```
return '';
```

Comment: All event handlers have an `event` parameter, it contains the details of what triggered the event.

Comment: And is it necessary to use it in this case?

Comment: It's there if your application wants to use it. If you don't need it, ignore it, just like the examples do.

Comment: If you are happy with the default message, use `event.preventDefault();` instead. I personally think it looks cleaner

Comment: There's probably nothing useful in it for this particular event. It's just part of the common event handling protocol.

Comment: @RGraham: It doesn't seem to work in Chrome: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload).